# Type of union type field

Tags: typescript

I have some interface describing messages:

```
    interface Message1 {
        name: "message1";
        data: any;
    }
    interface Message2 {
        name: "message2";
        data: any;
    }
    type Message = Message1 | Message2;
```

This is auto-generated interfaces/type from JSON-schema, and I can't easily change it.

I want to access the type of message name, ie `'message1' | 'message2'`, like `Message.type`.

Does someone know how to / if we can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
type MessageName = Message['name']

const a: MessageName = 'message1' // OK
const b: MessageName = 'message12131' // error
```

For more details about union types [check the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).